# how to add a checkbox in a listview of parsed data and put it into sqlite

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a parsed data in a listview.Now i want to integrate a checkbox in a listview ,and when they are selected i want to store that in sqlite database.
    Any idea how to do that.i have written the code for parsing and displaying ,this is my code

```
 package com.example.rotaryclubnew;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;



import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.StrictMode;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
public class Displaycontacts extends Activity{

    public static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/GetContact";

   public static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public static String METHOD_NAME1 = "GetContact";

    private static String URL = "http://115.119.182.114/Rotaryclub/RotaryService.asmx"; 

    String output="";
    ArrayList<String> contactsNamelist;
     ArrayList<String> contactsPoslist;
  //  TextView t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9;
    ListView lv;
     List<String> contactRecords = new ArrayList<String>();


/*
     static{
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }   */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.displaycontacts);




        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewtodisplayname);



     //CALL the web service method with the two parameters vname and nname



         Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  try {
                     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);     
              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                     envelope.dotNet=true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                     HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                     ht.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
              //       final  Object response = envelope.getResponse();

                //     final String str = response.toString();

                     request.addProperty("user_id", "3");
                        System.out.println("requesr for"+"3");
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        //httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
                        final SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                          runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){ 

                              public void run() {

                     int count=result.getPropertyCount();
                     System.out.println("in count "+count);
                      for (int i = 0; i<= count-1; i++) 
                      {
                          SoapObject result1=(SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);
                          contactRecords.add(result1.getProperty(2).toString());

                          System.out.println("in for loop "+result1.getProperty(2).toString());

                         // contactRecords.add(result1.getProperty(2).toString());

                      }

      }
              });
                  }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                  handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                }
              };
              lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"items selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Intent i1=new Intent(Displaycontacts.this, Displayofcontactsdetails.class);
                     /*i.putExtra("NAME",lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString());
                     i.putExtra("POS",contactsPoslist.get(arg2).toString());
                     System.out.println("main act put extra "+lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString()+contactsPoslist.get(arg2).toString());*/
                    // startActivity(i1);

                }
            });


              networkThread.start();





               }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Displaycontacts.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactRecords);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want update date in database on checked change in list then try this

```
     mHolder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);

                    mHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                            int id = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();

//Write your code for update database over hear and use id to get chacked data position
                                                    }
                    });
```

Comment: ok.but also guide me,how to integrate a checkbox in a listview

Comment: @abh22ishek : make rowxml with checkbox and inflate that view and set adapter with you list.

Comment: i have made a rowxml with checkbox,but dont know how to integrate to the listview.please if possible give the codes

Comment: @abh22ishek try to search base adapter and listview you will get lots of example

Comment: @abh22ishek try this link :: http://www.coderanch.com/t/513608/Android/Mobile/Multiple-Checkboxes-ListView

Comment: i solved the problem by just mentioning the android:choice="multiplechoice" of listview in main.xml and in main activity by adding..ArrayAdapter<string>aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Displaycontacts.this, android.R.layout.simple_multiple_choice_list,contactRecords);but i haven't put any condition on it,will it be effecient further?

Comment: ArrayAdapter<string>aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Displaycontacts.this, android.R.layout.simple_multiple_choice_list,contactRecords);but i haven't put any condition on it,will it be effecient?

Comment: on adding further functionalities

Comment: next thing is ,when i am selecting the names in the listview with checkbox,then my all details corresponding to that name will save to my sqlite database.i am not sure how to do it?can u tell me how to do it?i am using the above code to connect to the url